# Join condition in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to translate the following SQL to LINQ :

```
Select Person.*, Governorate.OptionName
from Person 
Left Join Option Governorate on Governorate.OptionListName='Governorate' 
and Person.GovernorateId=Governorate.GovernorateId
```

I did the following :

```
from person in db.persons
join governorate in db.Options 
on  new { Key1=person.GovernorateId,
         Key2=true} equals
    new { Key1=governorate.OptionValue,
         Key2= governorate.OptionListName equals "Governorate"}
select person, governorate
```

but this produces two errors:
1- For: `Key2= governorate.OptionListName equals "Governorate"`
    Syntax error for equals and Anonymus type declared for "Governorate"

2- For:  `select person, governorate`
the governorate can't be declared in this scope as it will give governorate a different meaning.

Comment: Beware: all of the 3 answers so far are for INNER joins, whereas based on your SQL you want an OUTER join. See MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) for details of how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from person in db.persons
   join governorate in db.Options 
       on  new { Key1=person.GovernorateId, Key2="Governorate"} equals
new { Key1=governorate.OptionValue, Key2= governorate.OptionListName  }
into g
select new {
             person = person, 
             governorates = g
           }
```

It gives you a collection of objects that each object has a `person` and a collection on `governorate` corresponding to that person.

If you want the result contain the pair of `person` and `governorate`:

```
from person in db.persons
   join governorate in db.Options 
       on  new { Key1=person.GovernorateId, Key2="Governorate"} equals
new { Key1=governorate.OptionValue, Key2= governorate.OptionListName  }
into groups
from g in groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
             person = person, 
             governorates = g.OptionName
           }
```

this returns a collection of objects that each object contains a pair of `person` and `governorate.OptionName`.

**Some explanation for the second query** from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

> The first step in producing a left outer join of two collections is to perform an inner join by using a group join.
>   The second step is to include each element of the first (left) collection in the result set even if that element has no matches in the right collection. This is accomplished by calling DefaultIfEmpty **on each sequence of matching elements from the group join**.

Comment: Is there a way to only select a specific field in governorate?

Comment: Yes , in  `select new {person = person,   someField = g.Select(y=>y.SomeFiled)  }`

Comment: This does an inner join, not a left join as required.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried to correct his initial attempt

Comment: @GaryMcGill, changed the second query to be an outer join, based on link you provided.

Comment: @T.Rahgooy Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please explain why you used groups instead of just adding DefaultIfEmpty in the db.options table?

Comment: @user3340627, I added some explanation for this

Answer (score 1):

```
from person in db.persons
join governorate in db.Options 
on   person.GovernorateId equals governorate.OptionValue  
where governorate.OptionListName =="Governorate"       
select person, governorate
```

OR 
You can try this

```
from person in db.persons
join governorate in db.Options.Where(x=>x.OptionListName =="Governorate") 
on   person.GovernorateId equals governorate.OptionValue 
select person, governorate
```

Eg: I tried this and it works perfectly.

```
from u in User_Accounts.Where(x=>x.User_Account_Type =="Client")
join a in Clients on u.Client_ID equals a.Client_ID
select u
```

Comment: I got an error "Operator && cannot be applied for operands of type int and string", it seems that it is comparing the OptionValue with OptionListName which is not supposed to happen

Comment: how about use where condition ? check my modified answer

Comment: The first query gives error: Cannot use local variable "governorate" before it is declared. also for "select person, governorate", a local variable governorate cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to governorate

Comment: The second query, also gave many errors, like for "where" : invalid expression term "where"

Comment: @user3340627 previously there's a spelling mistake in `Where`. It should start with 'W'

Answer (score 1):

```
from p in db.persons
join h in db.Options on p.GovernorateId equals h.OptionValue && h.OptionListName equals "Governorate" into t
 from rt in t

 select new
 {
       p.person, h.governorate
 }).ToList();
```